# Bad sound quality in CS:GO and Minecraft

Tags: kubuntu, pulseaudio

I recently switched from Windows to Kubuntu 21.04. The sound quality is good in everything except Minecraft and CS:GO. It sounds kind of like it was coming from a tin can, if you know what I mean. I have the SteelSeries Arctis Pro headset.
How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line .conf file and test! In case of a problem, the added rows should be deleted (or change value sample-format, sample-rate).

nano /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

```
default-sample-format = float32le
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 41000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 2
default-fragment-size-msec = 125
resample-method = soxr-vhq
#enable-lfe-remixing = no
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 9
rlimit-rtprio = 9
daemonize = no
```

nano  /etc/asound.conf

```
# Use PulseAudio plugin hw
pcm.!default {
   type plug
   slave.pcm hw
}
```

- https://medium.com/@gamunu/enable-high-quality-audio-on-linux-6f16f3fe7e1f
- https://linuxreviews.org/PulseAudio
- http://sox.sourceforge.net/
- https://lastique.github.io/src_test/
- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/
- https://linux.die.net/man/5/pulse-daemon.conf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)